# Remote MongoDB Dump Failure

Tags: mongodb

I hope you can help me. I am trying to make a data dump on a MongoDB remotely, but am getting an error.

**I use the following command from my Windows CMD console to create the backup:**

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\imports>mongodump --host 10.13.9.210 --port 29039 --out E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump
```

**It all seems to run and dump and write,**

```
2015-11-13T15:56:30.159+0200    writing IOWA.VENDORITEM to E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA\VENDORITEM.bson
2015-11-13T15:56:30.162+0200    writing IOWA.CALLCLOSURECODE metadata to E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA\CALLCLOSURECODE.metadata.json
2015-11-13T15:56:30.171+0200    writing IOWA.PRICELISTITEM metadata to E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA\PRICELISTITEM.metadata.json
2015-11-13T15:56:30.193+0200    done dumping IOWA.CALLCLOSURECODE (0 documents)
2015-11-13T15:56:30.194+0200    writing IOWA.BULLETINBOARD to E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA\BULLETINBOARD.bson
2015-11-13T15:56:30.205+0200    done dumping IOWA.PRICELISTITEM (0 documents)
2015-11-13T15:56:30.205+0200    writing IOWA.BINLOCATION to E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA\BINLOCATION.bson
```

**But then I get this ERROR:**

```
2015-11-13T15:56:30.270+0200    Failed: error creating bson file `E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA1\db.getCollection('MASTER').distinct("_t").bson`: open E:\Mongo\Data\Backup\Dump\IOWA1\db.getCollection('MASTER').distinct("_t").bson: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even i had this issue and came to know its an bug. workaround for this would be dumping by passing the DB

```
mongodump -d "database_name"
```

try this may resolve your issue. Make sure you have enough space in the File system.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It ran without any errors, showing the progress etc., but the weirdest thing....it does not show in either of my specified "out" directory, nor the default C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\dump directory. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I agree, if it not there then it should be in the home directory \dump and db name assuming your home diretory is c:\users\onmyway then you can find the dump in 
c:\users\onmyway\dump\<dbname>\*.bson

Comment: No luck. will let the server gurus check it out....

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: another easier way is search in your computer for *.bson